# How to ONLY detect a particular language using cloud vision api in python and ignore others?

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I want to detect korean language from the image and only korean. I don't want to detect english even if it occurs in the image. I can't seem to find any way on internet that could do this for me.

**What I've tried:**

I'm aware of the the `image_context` attribute and am already using it to mention only korean but that didn't ignore english text. I did:

```py
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image, image_context={"language_hints": ["ko"]})
```

**What I want?**

Is there a way to not detect English language from the image?

Or is there a way to block certain symbols from being detected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `image_context` attribute is not used to restrict the language that you want to extract on a single image. It does the opposite as it helps to amplify and get better results for understanding the language. [1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages)

> Providing a language hint to the service is not required, but can be done if the service is having trouble detecting the language used in your image.

> If the language hint is left blank, we will attempt to auto-detect the
> most appropriate language. The TEXT_DETECTION endpoint will
> auto-detect only a subset of supported languages, while the
> DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION endpoint will auto-detect the full set of
> supported languages.

One way to achieve your use-case might be by manipulating the return response from the Vision API. You can extract only the Korean characters or exclude the results with English text.

```
"textAnnotations": [
    {
      "locale": "ko",
      "description": "牛牛面馆\n",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 159,
            "y": 212
          },
          {
            "x": 947,
            "y": 212
          },
          {
            "x": 947,
            "y": 354
          },
          {
            "x": 159,
            "y": 354
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Or you can file a feature request for this.

Comment: That was quite the solution i was looking forward to.
And if you think that the question was helpful, do upvote it so that It might come handy to someone else looking for it.